# Aren't all Android tablets supposed to be recognized by ADB/Android studio?

Tags: android, adb, mobile-devices, android-debug

I have a Nexus 7 which is recognized just fine, but I'm trying to get a 10" to work with and have been through two (iRulu and e-Passion (running KitKat), neither of which show up in ADB  or are recognized as a connected device in Android Studio.  I've downloaded any drivers I could find to no avail, but is there something else I'm missing, or should I just invest in a more expensive tablet?

Comment: Is USB Debugging enabled in the developer options on the device? Is the USB mode set to Camera PTP and not Media MTP?

Comment: Depends on your OS.  On OSX, everything just works.  On Linux, you have to add each tablet to your udev rules.  On Windows, you have to track down and install drivers for each device.

Comment: Although I don't think KitKat still has the option to change between PTP and MTP.

Comment: You probably haven't added the tablet ids to the udev file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the price of the tablet. It might be a permissions thing. If you're running in Linux, try killing the running adb server

```
adb kill-server
```

and then su to root and

```
adb devices
```

to see if they then show up.